# Drag and Drop - Ghost Image Size Increases After Every Drag

Tags: javascript, svg, dom, safari, drag-and-drop

I'm having an issue, with the Ghost Image / Icon that appears on Drag, for Safari specifically.

In the sample project, I am adding Base64Encoded SVG Images to the DOM.  Each time I attempt to drag one of the Images, the Ghost Image gets larger.  This behavior doesn't seem to be happening on Chrome.

Ultimately, the drag and drop is meant to allow Users to insert the selected image onto a canvas (using a 3rd Party library).  However, the issue occurs even without it.

Not entirely sure what is going on, but any help is most appreciated.  I tried using the setDragImage() method in the Drag and Drop API docs, CSS to change the Ghost Image / Icon as outlined here (link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/DragAndDrop.html) but no luck...

Thanks!

Link to Project:
https://replit.com/@Zeroays/Drag-and-Drop-SIMPLE-TEST#script.js

Comment: On my iPad (IOS 14/Safari) the ghost image is always slightly larger than the original but it's the same size on each drag  - are you saying it's larger the second time you drag than the first? Are you seeing that on MacOS or IOS?

Comment: Alternative is to not use a (default) ghost-image, but move the SVG element itself: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/

Comment: @AHaworth It's interesting that you are running on an iPad.  Haven't tested there at all.  Running the Code on a MacOS with Safari Version 13.1.  Here's a link to a GIF that explains what is going on. (Link: https://media.giphy.com/media/GDis6YnP5PRCLCw3Z8/giphy.gif)

Comment: Interesting, on my iPad/Safari, the 'ghost' is an actual replica of the image, only very slightly bigger, and its doesn't grow in size.